# How to remove deprecation from AmazonSNSClient?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm trying to configure SNS in my application. For Aws credential, I'm using AmazonSNSClient.My AmazonSNSClient and withRegion are deprecated what shall I do?

MY code :-

AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials (
                "*****************",
                "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");

```
    AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider=new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider ( awsCredentials );

    AmazonSNSClient amazonSNSClient=new AmazonSNSClient ( awsCredentialsProvider )
                                       .withRegion ( Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
    String msg = "this is a t---est";
    PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest("arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:000000000000:topic", msg);

    PublishResult publishResult = amazonSNSClient.publish ( publishRequest );

    System.out.println("MessageId - " + publishResult.getMessageId());
```

Comment: You could start by [reading the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use client builder instead of directly using client constructors since it has been deprecated by the latest SDK version.

```
AmazonSNS sns = AmazonSNSClient.builder()
                    .withRegion("<your region>")
                    .withClientConfiguration(<configuration>)
                    .withCredentials(<your credentials>)
                    .build();
```